# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'i2c.so'

Tags: c#, c, dll

Running a proximity sensor program, but unfortunately I cant compile the program due to errors in importing the DLLs.

This is the error:
[image]

The DLL are from the i2c.cs file:

```
private static class I2CNativeLib
{
    [DllImport("i2c.so", EntryPoint = "Get", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int Get(string i2Cbusid, string deviceaddress, string dataaddress);

    [DllImport("i2c.so", EntryPoint = "Set", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int Set(string i2Cbusid, string deviceaddress, string dataaddress, string datavalue, int force);
}
```

For reference, here is the full i2c.cs file and below that is the main file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RPi.I2C.Net
{
    internal abstract class i2c
    {
        internal static Dictionary<string, int> Constants { get; set; }

        protected static int Set16(string i2Cbusid, string deviceaddress, string dataaddress, string datavalue, int force)
        {
            var value = (UInt16)Convert.ToInt16(datavalue, 16);

            var add1 = (UInt16)Convert.ToInt16(dataaddress, 16);
            var add2 = ++add1;

            var msb = GetAsHexString(value >> 8);
            var lsb = GetAsHexString(value & 0xFF);
            Console.WriteLine("16-bit: Writing 16-bit Value: {0} as 2 8-bit values {1} and {2}", GetAsHexString(value), msb, lsb);

            Console.WriteLine("16-bit: Writing {0} to address {1}", msb, GetAsHexString(add1));
            var data = I2CNativeLib.Set(i2Cbusid, deviceaddress, GetAsHexString(add1), msb, force); //set msb byte/8 bits
            Console.WriteLine("16-bit: Response to msb: {0}", data);


            Console.WriteLine("16-bit: Writing {0} to address {1}", lsb, GetAsHexString(add2));
            data |= I2CNativeLib.Set(i2Cbusid, deviceaddress, GetAsHexString(add2), lsb, force); //set lsb byte/8 bits
            Console.WriteLine("16-bit: Response to msb |= lsb: {0}", data);
            return data;

        }

        protected static byte Set8(string i2Cbusid, string deviceaddress, string dataaddress, string datavalue, int force)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("8-bit: Writing {0} to address {1}", datavalue, dataaddress);
            //8-bit
            return (byte)I2CNativeLib.Set(i2Cbusid, deviceaddress, dataaddress, datavalue, force);
        }
        protected static byte Get(string i2Cbusid, string deviceaddress, string dataaddress)
        {
            return (byte)I2CNativeLib.Get(i2Cbusid, deviceaddress, dataaddress);
        }

        internal string Busid = string.Empty;
        internal bool DoWork = false;

        protected i2c()
        {
            Constants = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }

        internal static int GetConstantAsByte(string key)
        {
            int value;
            Constants.TryGetValue(key, out value);
            return value;
        }
        internal static string GetConstantAsString(string key)
        {
            int value;
            Constants.TryGetValue(key, out value);
            return "0x" + value.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');
        }
        internal static string GetAsHexString(uint value)
        {
            return "0x" + value.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');
        }
        internal static string GetAsHexString(int value)
        {
            return "0x" + value.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');
        }
        internal byte GetValue8(string deviceAddress, string dataAddress)
        {
            var result = Get(
                Busid,
                GetConstantAsString(deviceAddress),
                GetConstantAsString(dataAddress)
            );
            return result;
        }
        internal UInt16 GetValue16(string deviceAddress, string dataAddress)
        {
            var result = (UInt16)(Get(Busid, GetConstantAsString(deviceAddress), GetConstantAsString(dataAddress)) << 8);
            result |= Get(Busid, GetConstantAsString(deviceAddress), GetConstantAsString(dataAddress));

            return result;
        }
        internal abstract void Start();
        internal virtual void Stop()
        {
            DoWork = false;
        }
        private static class I2CNativeLib
        {
            [DllImport("i2c.so", EntryPoint = "Get", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int Get(string i2Cbusid, string deviceaddress, string dataaddress);

            [DllImport("i2c.so", EntryPoint = "Set", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int Set(string i2Cbusid, string deviceaddress, string dataaddress, string datavalue, int force);
        }
    }
    }
```

Here is the main file:

```
using System;

namespace i2c
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] argv)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Communication with VCNL4000");
            var vcnl4000 = new VCNL4000("1", 100);
            vcnl4000.ProximityReading += sensor_ProximityReading;
            var productId = vcnl4000.ProductID;
            OutputValue(productId, "Product ID");
            vcnl4000.Start();

            //Console.WriteLine("Starting Communication with ADS1115");
            //var ads1115 = new ADS1115("1");
            //ads1115.Message += ads1115_Message;
            //ads1115.SingleEndedConversionReading += ads1115_ConversionReading;
            //ads1115.Start();                

            Console.WriteLine("Press Esc key to stop");
            do
            {
                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

            //ads1115.Stop();
            vcnl4000.Stop();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void ads1115_Message(object sender, ConverterMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        OutputValue(e.Message, "Convertor");
    }
    private static void OutputValue(string response, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + " Response: {0}", response);
    }
    private static void ads1115_ConversionReading(object sender, SingleEndedConversionEventArgs e)
    {
        var _sender = (ADS1115)sender;
        OutputValue(e.Data, "Conversion Reading");
    }
    static void sensor_ProximityReading(object sender, ProximtyEventArgs e)
    {
        var sensor = (VCNL4000)sender;
        OutputValue(e.Proximity, "Proximity Reading");
        OutputValue(e.RawValue, "Proximity Raw Value");
    }
    private static void OutputValue(int response, string message) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message  + " Response: {0} (0x{1})", response, response.ToString("X"));
    }
    private static void OutputValue(decimal response, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + " Response: {0}", response);
    }
    private static void OutputValue(float response, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + " Response: {0}", response);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which platform? If it's under Windows, shouldn't you have i2c.DLL instead of i2c.so? (only guessing from 'Press any key to continue . . .' message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognise the code sample as code I wrote and shared on GitHub, so maybe I can help here. I recently added a ReadMe.txt file with this information:

> The i2c.so file can be placed in the same folder as the mono assembly
>   (bin folder) or copied to the /usr/lib/ folder to be available to all
>   mono assemblies. In some cases you may see DLL File Not Found
>   exceptions, but placing in /usr/lib should resolve that.
>
> So copy the i2c.so file to /usr/lib/ directory
>
> linux command:
>
> **cp i2c.so /usr/lib/**
>
> To rebuild the i2c.so file, from shell, "CD" to the location of the
>   files, and run the "make" command.
>
> linux command:
>
> make
>
> "make" will run the build defined in the makefile definition.
>
> Code borrowed from i2ctools, v3.1.0, see Credits.txt and Licence.txt

The important part is copying the i2c.so file to the /usr/lib/ directory.

At the bottom of the file is a clue on how to build i2c.so in the first place if you dont have it, or you need an updated version.

Might be worth pointing out the code was originally intended to run on a Raspberry Pi, using Mono.

https://github.com/silentbobbert/pi_sensors

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your "i2c.so" in the correct location.

Please read this wonderful link [Interop with Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries#Library_Handling) on how to make shared object libraries work with C#.

Seeing the `DLLNotFoundException` we can start by looking for where the .so actually is, and whether the naming is correct.

Based on which platform you are working on the directories are looked at in the following order:
Note: This is copied from the link provided above:

**Windows**

> The directory from which the application loaded.
>       The current directory
>       The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory() function to get
>       the path of this directory.
>       The 16-bit system directory.
>       The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory() function to get
>       the path of this directory.
>       The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

**Linux**

> User's LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
>      The list of libraries cached in /etc/ld.so.cache.
>      /lib, followed by /usr/lib.

Please read the article.